# Unable to add a vCenter server to VMware Horizon

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I've installed `VMware Horizon` on a virtual machine which is on my ESX. In order to configure it, I have to specify the `vCenter server` into the Horizon's configuration. But when I try to specify the `vCenter` into the configuration, it says that it's only possible to add one `vCenter` server (I don't have the exact error in English but in French it's `Seul un serveur vCenter Server peut être ajouté`). It's a fresh install and I really don't know why I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the automatic install, I've reinstalled every modules of Horizon separately (it offers more options) and it works ! Problem solved.

Comment: I know, I just have to wait 22 hours.